# Limits of a two-variable function...

Tags: calculus

Consider the function $$f(x,y) = \frac{xy}{5x^2+3y^2}.$$ Determine the limits as $x$ and $y$ approach $\infty$, $-\infty$ and the origin $(0,0)$.
If the limit is approached along the line $y = cx$, for $c\in \mathbb{R}$, then
\begin{equation*}
f(x,y) = f(x,cx) = \frac{xcx}{5x^2+3(cx)^2} = \frac{cx^2}{5x^2+3c^2x^2} = \frac{cx^2}{x^2(5+3c^2)} = \frac{c}{5+3c^2}.
\end{equation*}
Hence, $\lim_{\substack{(x,y)\to (\infty,\infty) \\ \text{along} \, \, y = cx}} \frac{xy}{5x^2+3y^2}$ does NOT exist as this will have different values as we change $c$ contradicting the uniqueness of limits.
Is this correct? How would we do this for $(-\infty,-\infty)$ and $(0,0)$? Thanks.

Comment: What you've done is perfect!

Comment: What you have done works for $(0,0)$ and $(-\infty,-\infty)$ also.